# How to add space after every comma inside text?

Tags: javascript, html

I have that JSON:

```js
var tmp = "{\"query\":[[1,\"ADMIN\"],[2,\"USER\"]]}"
var tmpJSON = JSON.parse(tmp);
document.getElementById("text").value = tmpJSON.query;
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

**Can someone tell me how i can add space after every comma?** I mean 1 space or more, for example: 2x space after every comma.

Comment: You could use `tmpJSON.query.flat().join(', ')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string .replace method like if value is a string

```
value.replace(/,/g, ',  ')
```

For ref check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: This will also have “strange effects” when the JSON contains strings with commas..